# how to replace background image in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change a background image when user click a button.

after user click a button the following code execute.

```
 $('body').css('background',"url('test2.png') no-repeat center center")
```

however, My css has more attributes like the following:

```
body {
    background: url('test.png') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-color: #00ABBA;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

By execute my js code, it will kill all other css attribute and only replace the background image. I know I can append all the css attribute to my js but I feel like there is a better way to do this. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: Why would it overwrite other styles? If you just want to replace the image, set the `background-image` style only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('body').css('background-image','url(test2.png)');`

Just target `background-image` rather than the universal `background`.

**All of your other styles will remain in place.**

Comment: Yep, that's better... when Using Full Size backgrounds you should have all your attributes separated. Background-Image, Background-Size, Background-Position X, Y, etc etc